# Optimal denoising of a few features for latent variable modeling

Tags: pca, feature-selection, sequential-analysis

I am fitting latent variable models to noisy, high-dimensional data. The dimension is 15,000 to 20,000; there are 2,000 observations. There is a certain latent structure that I observe -- essentially, a set of clusters. Certain features change very clearly from cluster to cluster. Most do not.

I now have the opportunity to choose a limited number of variables and denoise them (clean them up). If I choose variables that don't depend on my cluster labels, they'll just be very obviously useless, instead of probably useless. If I choose variables that align perfectly with my inferred latent variables, I am afraid I won't learn anything new. So, my intuition is to choose variables that are weakly correlated with the inferred latent variables.

How should I choose variables in order to gain the most information? Bonus for answers that discuss whether a given strategy will bias the results.

P.S. I don't know what to search for to get at this topic. Pointers appreciated.

P.P.S. You can reasonably assume the data are drawn from a low-rank matrix with a Poisson distribution for the response, i.e. $Z=UV^T$ for skinny $U, V$ and $X_{ij}|Z_{ij}\sim Poisson(X_{ij})$, with only $X$ observed. The denoising will increase the counts $X_{ij}$ for all $i$ and a few $j$, so that $\frac{X_{ij} }{ \sum_i X_{ij}}$ gets less noisy.

Comment: Also: I'd appreciate answers that address whether and how I could use this approach to resolve clusters that are not distinguished (or only weakly distinguished) by the current dataset.